# convergence of $ \sum \frac{1+\cos(n)}{n+1}$

Tags: calculus

I was testing with some convergence series criteria, but I'm in trouble with the next:

$$ \sum \frac{1+\cos(n)}{n+1}$$

I am sure that direct comparison criteria works, but what is the correct series to compare?

Comment: I wrote it in WolframAlpha but couldn't conclude nothing :s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. $\sum \frac{\cos n}{n+1}$ converges by [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test)$\color{blue}{^{[1]}}$.
2. $\sum \frac{1}{n+1}$ diverges by 
   [Integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test) against $\int_0^n \frac{dx}{1+x}$.
3. $\sum \frac{1+\cos n}{n+1}$ diverges because it is a sum of a convergent and a divergence sequence.

**Notes**

$\color{blue}{[1]}$ To apply the Dirichlet's Test, one need to verify two conditions

- $\frac{1}{n+1}$ is monotonic decreasing and converges to $0$.
- The partials sums $\sum_{n=1}^N \cos n$ is bounded.

The $1^{st}$ condition is obvious, the $2^{nd}$ condition is also true because
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \cos n = \Re \left[ \sum_{n=1}^N e^{in} \right] = \Re\left[ e^i \frac{1-e^{iN}}{1-e^i}\right]
\quad\implies\quad
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \cos n\right| \le \frac{2}{| 1 - e^i|} = \frac{1}{\sin\frac12}
$$
If you don't like the use of complex number, you can also derive same inequality using trigonometry.

Comment: Could you explain, how to apply Dirichlet's test in the first series please?

Comment: @BrallanAguilar Given series $\sum_n a_n$ converges and $sum_n b_n$ diverges. If series $\sum_n (a_n + b_n)$ converges, it will lead to a contradiction that $\sum_n b_n = \sum_n ((a_n + b_n) - a_n)$ converges.

Comment: What exactly is the constant M for which $\left|\sum_{n=0}^N\cos(n)\right|<M,\ \forall\ N\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$\cos n\ge0$ often enough. The sequence $n$ hits at least one point of every interval $[(k-1/4)2\pi,(k+1/4)2\pi]$, $k\ge1$. This is enough to have the series diverge.